# Distinguish a single and double tap on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added an `UITapGestureRecogniser` to my tableViewCell which recognizes if the user double tapped a cell. If I double tap the cell, the function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets automatically called. I just want that the func of the gesturerecogniser gets called if the user do a double tap on a cell and not both. Does someone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: How does the user know to double-tap the cell? What's double-tapping do?

Comment: Add some code of your tap gesture

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad function :

```
let aSelector : Selector = “start:”
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

let bSelector : Selector = “stop:”
let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: bSelector)
doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

tapGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTapGesture)
```

The action aSelector will be called on single tap and bSelector on double tap.